# How to write multiple "do" statments in if/else statment nested in a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I'm trying to write an if/else statement in R that will execute two expressions within the same else step. I.e., I want my code to accomplish the same as the following pseudoR code:

```
for(i in some range){

if(statement dependent on i) do(A)

else do(both B & C)

}
```

where A, B, and C are expressions that will assign new values to different vectors or data.frames depending on the statement in the argument of if. I've tried the following (in proper R syntax):

```
for(i in some range){

if(statement dependent on i) A

else B C

}
```

but this only includes B at the else step (it evaluates C at every step in the for loop, not just when the if statement is false). Adding parentheses or braces only messes up the if/else/for syntax. Including the logical operator "&" hasn't worked either. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use curly braces, e.g. `if(expr) A else {B; C}`

Answer (score 2):

Following the [R coding conventions](http://www1.maths.lth.se/help/R/RCC/#6.1%20Layout) would make this a non-issue.  Andrie's comment is correct.